# tips for wading in knee deep water where water moccasins could roam

Tags: hiking, rivers, snakes, waterproof-clothing, solo-hiking

Lately I've taken up a new hobby: taking pictures of train trestle bridges. There's one that goes over the San Gabriel river in Texas that I can get within half a mile of but any further than that would require I wade through a good length of knee deep water.

I can't approach this particular trestle bridge from land because the land is all gated off private property. But, in Texas, [navigable waterways are public property](https://tpwd.texas.gov/publications/nonpwdpubs/water_issues/rivers/navigation/riddell/navigability.phtml) so I can approach the train trestle bridge that way.

The problem with wading in the water is that there could be water moccasins and I doubt I could out wade a water moccasin.

I have seem rain boots that go about up to my knee. Would those be sufficient?

I mean, maybe I could do a kayak or standup paddle board, too, but I'd have to lug those around for a decent distance before I'd be able to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walked and floated miles on the San Gabriel, several times ; never seen a cotton mouth there.  Two grandsons were with me who would have likely flushed them out. I have seen them in E TX a few times , they have not been aggressive as their reputation claims. More like copperheads which are common here ; That is , confident because they are not afraid of humans like most snakes.